# Object of type 'JSONDecodeError' is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, django, rest, api

I have just started learning Django and was trying to create an API. It is a simple API which fetches a definition from the table and returns it as a response. But whenever I am trying to send a keyword in the request, I am getting the error, **Object of type 'JSONDecodeError' is not JSON serializable**. What am I doing wrong in here?

```
@api_view(['POST'])
 def getdetails(request):
  try:
    connection = sqlite3.connect('{}.db'.format('insure'))
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    plan = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))

    cursor.execute(

        """SELECT INSURANCE_TYPE_DESC FROM tblInsurancePlans WHERE INSURANCE_TYPE LIKE '%{}%'""".format(plan)

    )

    rows = cursor.fetchall()

    for row in rows:
        return JsonResponse(str(row), safe=False)

except Exception as e:
    return Response(e)
```

However, when I try to hard-code the keyword (plan), it works and I get the response.

Comment: And a line `raise` refore the last return to see the real error. Then make sure errors are properly serialized.

Comment: Now it says **Exception: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)** @KlausD.

Comment: Probably the result of `request.body.decode('utf-8')` is not a JSON. Who posts to this API and what?

Comment: Sorry! I didn't understand your question. The request is basically just a word. Like **retirement** or **term** @tevemadar

Comment: `json.loads()` ***load***s ***json*** from a ***s***tring, containing JSON-encoded data. A mere word is not JSON-encoded data, at a minimum it would have to be surrounded with quotation marks. Perhaps you are looking for `plan=request.body.decode('utf-8')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you `query` the database for fetching more than one row ,`result` comes as a `queryset (orderDict)` in django, so you have to `serialize` them ,and should `convert` to proper format .

`response`  will accept only `json` data according to api .

for [more info on how to use serializers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/).

- ***Note:***

  After returning one `response` the `connection` between server and client gets `closed` .
  from one `api request` you can send only one response .
  but here you are trying to  return `multiple responses` .this will `not work` .
  *you will have to send all data in single response.*

Comment: I modified the query to fetch only 1 result. Still getting the same error. Apologies if I am unable to grasp in one go, I am still learning.

Comment: @SudiptoMukherjee i mentioned link above. read that . queryset is a datastructure which needs to be convert to normal dictionary so that we can do other operations on queryset.  for conversion we use serilaization.

Comment: That article helped. Thanks.